# Arrow notation in slice category

Tags: haskell, category-theory

> If `CatC` is a category and A any object of `CatC`, the slice category `CatC`/A is described this way:
>
> SC-1 An object of `CatC`/A is an arrow `f: C -> A` of `CatC` for some object C.
>
> SC-2 An arrow of `CatC`/A from `f: C -> A` to `f': C' -> A` is an arrow `h: C -> C'` with the property that `f = f' . h`.
>
> SC-3 The composite of `h: f -> f'` and `h': f -> f''` is `h' . h`.

What is the type of arrow in `CatC`/A?

`C -> C`(object in `CatC` to object in `CatC`) or `f -> f'`(object in `CatC`/A to object in `CatC`/A).

Comment: Well, the definition is clear: "An arrow of `CatC`/A from `f: C -> A` to `f': C' -> A` is an arrow `h: C -> C`'" so an arrow of `CatC`/A is an arrow of `CatC`.

Comment: Where does the quoted text come from?

Comment: Written in Agda it's: `_⇒ₛ_ : ∀ {A B C} -> A ⇒ C -> B ⇒ C -> Set _; f ⇒ₛ g = ∃ λ h -> g ∘ h ≈ f`. So it's an arrow `A ⇒ B` in the original category, equipped with commutativity proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just terminological confusion "type" of an arrow in `CatC/A` is an arrow in `CatC/A` between objects of `CatC/A`. The *data* (or content if you prefer) of such an arrow is an arrow in `CatC` coupled with an additional proof obligation. Your arrows in `CatC/A` are thus not just arrows in `CatC`, but are the pairs of such arrows with the proofs that they satisfy the required commutative diagram.